# How to name a method properly?

Tags: objective-c, method-names

It's more a question about English grammar, but nevertheless, can you tell me which one is a correct method name? This ambiguity drives me crazy.

Method **linesNumber** returns number of "rows" in some sort of table.
I personally like "numberOfLines" variant, but linesNumber is shorter...

```
#pragma mark - RCGroupDataSource methods

- (NSUInteger)linesNumber { // ???: or numberOfLines or lineNumbers
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, as a native English speaker I find "linesNumber" awkward and nonobvious. I'd go with "numberOfRowsInTable" as Anoop Vaidya suggests.

Comment: `numberOfLines` would be correct the others wouldn't make sense for the purpose of why you are using it. When naming methods try to have them make sense for the purpose of the method. So if you had a method returning the number of rows in section have `numberOfRowsInSection` or if it was a calculation have have a method called `calculation` and so on it would be good naming convention. Also Anoop Vaidya is correct why not use `numberOfRowsInTable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always give full name as you can.

> Method linesNumber returns number of "rows" in some sort of table.

why not use `numberOfRowsInTable`

You can refer [AppleDocumentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) and [CocoaDevCentral](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php)

Comment: I'd also like to add that methods are typically actions so it's also good practice to put a verb in the name (GetNumberOfRowsInTable).  You beat me to this by just a few seconds

Comment: @brenton I don't think "get" methods in Objective-C often, if ever, actually have "get" in their names.

Comment: if the class is a table i would go only for numberOfRows, as in table would be implicit by calling the method on a Table object. otherwise up for the Anoop suggestion

Comment: **NO** dont put Get and Put in cocoa, Have you seen anywhere in cocoa framework as GetString or getString?

Comment: brenton, it's a method from a datasource - should it still has verbal form?

Comment: @brenton NO do not use get or GET this is bad naming convention in cocoa. You can have set but they don't have get on there getters. it is generally just something like `- (NSString*)name;` as the getter and `- (void)setName:(NSString*)aName;` as the setter.

Answer (score 0):

Describe what is being done:-

```
getNumberOfLines
```

The other could be ambiguous

```
getLineNumbers
```

Sound more like a plural, ie an array of numbers.

Comment: Don't use `get` this is not used in cocoa anywhere. Bad naming convention for this language.

Comment: agree that latter should return an array :)